# Metadata lost when saving photo using PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, phphotolibrary

I used to save a photo to the camera roll using ALAssetLibrary's writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock, but that is now deprecated in iOS 9.0, so I switched to PHPhotoLibrary's version which looks like

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
}completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success){
        NSLog(@"Image Saved!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

This saves the image itself, but loses the metadata (exif ect) and I can't find any fixes of how to preserve this data when I save the photo. Any help would be appreciated. TYIA

Comment: Been trying to figure out how to remove exif data without rewriting sources. This did it :) One man's problem is another man's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the method

```
creationRequestForAssetFromImage:(UIImage *)image;
```

saves only image data. It doesn't include metadata.

If you want to save a image with metadata, you can do it by the following step.

First Save your image in temporary folder and get its path as NSURL.
Then Call the method

```
creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:(NSURL *)fileURL;
```

with the NSURL you get in First step.

Comment: @MitchD Sorry. I don't know the exact code to do same things in Android.
But it's possible, just save files on storage and register them on media store.

Comment: For iOS 9+, you can skip the intermediate file step and do `let request = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()`, and then `request.addResource(with:data:options:)` using the image data you've added your metadata to, all within the PHPhotoLibrary `performChanges` block.

Comment: @Undrea Thank you for your information. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: So is it possible to use `creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:(NSURL *)fileURL;` that to write exif to a rendered uiimage?